# Finding a basis for the intersection of two subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I'll try to write this as best as I can...

Let the following $U_1, U_2$ be subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^4$

$$
U_1 = 
\begin{Bmatrix}
(x, y, z, w) : z-y+2w = 0
\end{Bmatrix}
$$

$$
U_2 = 
\begin{Bmatrix}
(x, y, z, w) : z-y+2w = 0, x=2z
\end{Bmatrix}
$$

Find a basis for the subspace $(U_1 \cap U_2)$

I have found the bases

$$
B_1 = 
\begin{Bmatrix}
(1, 1, 0, 0), (0, 2, 0, 1), (0, 0, 1, 0)
\end{Bmatrix}
$$
$$
B_2 = 
\begin{Bmatrix}
(2, 2, 1, 0), (0, 2, 0, 1)
\end{Bmatrix}
$$

for $U_1, U_2$ respectively, but do not know where to go from here, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hint: $U_2\subset U_1$.

Comment: @DidierPiau

I see that $U_2$ is really $U_1$ with the extra condition that $x=2z$. So the elements of $(U_1 \cap U_2)$ are of the form $(2z, 2z+2w, z, w)$. So a basis for $(U_1 \cap U_2)$ is {(2, 2, 1, 0), (0, 2, 0, 1)}

is this correct? Also, for subspaces with much more complicated rules, is there a way to derive a basis for the intersection, with the bases for each subspace? thanks

Comment: A tip: In general (unlike in this specific artificial problem), the bases for $U_1$ and $U_2$ do not directly help in finding a basis for $U_1 \cap U_2$. (In contrast, it is easier to write down a basis for $U_1 + U_2$ given bases for $U_1$ and $U_2$.)

Comment: @Srivatsan I see, I just thought I'd check to see if the bases for each subspace came in handy when working this out, cheers!

Comment: The sets $B_1$ and $B_2$ are not bases for $U_1$ and $U_2$.  Check your calculations.

Comment: @MichaelJoyce I checked with the official answers and they listed the same bases. What is your reasoning for them not being bases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $U_{2}\subset U_{1}$, you have $U_{1}\cap U_{2}=U_{2}$ and for $U_{2}$ for you already found a base (incase that's calculated correctly). I got a different base for $U_{2}$ but there are plenty of different bases for it.

Comment: Not sure why I didn't see it wasn't contained before, thanks!